"Your solution contains files outside the solution folder which will not be included" When trying to push to repo, how to push all libraries?
I'm trying to push my repo to a new github repo, here's what it looks like in VS 2022:

And here's in my file system:

And when I go inside the _.API folder

As you can see I made sure to have a folder with all of the solution's folders in it, however the .csproj is in the _.API folder.
When I try to push my code to a new repo through Visual Studio 2022 I get this message:

Your solution contains files outside the solution folder which will not be included

I pushed it once anyway and there was only the files within the _.API folder so the .csproj and all but there was no reference to the other folders, once it was every library but without the folder containing the .csproj because I think I tried to push it a level higher in the file system ( in this case the _.Website-Copy ) but I'm not sure.
How can I push all my files and libraries to a new repo without any mistake ?

In which folder did you create the local git repository (where you ran git init)? Which of the folders contains a .git directory?

You push commits, not files separately. Are those files committed? Check what is in HEAD (or appropriate branch) with git ls-tree -r HEAD and make sure they are listed

@dan1st I haven’t created anything yet I was waiting for suggestions

@eftshift0 I know but nothing has been committed yet because it seems like it’s going to commit the API project only

I don't know VS but the message looks like you already created a local repository (and maybe also added some files). This might have happened when telling it to put the solution(?) under source control.

@dan1st I've checked the file system and there is no .git directory, so I don't think there is a local directory at the moment

Then I guess you could try running the git init command in the parent directory (where all of your projects are located).

Ok I can try that but if I do this, when I publish it through a 3rd party like railway that uses github as their way to publish work, can it find the .csproj this way ? I was trying to publish it to railway that's where all this happened

@dan1st wait I just realized something, would it be better if I had first created a blank solution and THEN create the _.API and every other library ? would that be the solution ? because here I created the Web Api first and then added libraries and stuff and that might be why it's a headache. What do you think ?

I don't know about VS and solutions but having the projects as subdirectories in the solution directory may be easier.
